# Publish to Azure fails with " Unrecognized link extension 'contentLibExtension'" Error

Tags: azure, webdeploy, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to publish ASP.NET MVC 6 App to Azure with Visual Studio 2015 CTP. And getting the following error

`Publishing with publish method [MSDeploy]
Calling msdeploy with the command: ["C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -source:IisApp='C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\AspNetPublish\NgCalendar-28\wwwroot' -dest:IisApp='ngcalendar',ComputerName='https://ngcalendar.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd',UserName='$ngcalendar',Password='{PASSWORD-REMOVED-FROM-LOG}',IncludeAcls='False',AuthType='Basic' -verb:sync -enableLink:contentLibExtension  -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -retryAttempts:2  ]
INVOKEPOWERSHELL(0,0): Error : Unrecognized link extension 'contentLibExtension'.
INVOKEPOWERSHELL(0,0): Error count: 1.`

Not sure where it's coming from and how to tweak it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error.
In my case the problem was an old version of "msdeploy.exe".

After some searching I found one "msdeploy.exe" in the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" which caused the problem and another one in the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe".

As I don't know how to change the path in Visual Studio to the newer version, I just saved the old folder and copied the complete content of the new folder into the old.

After this everything worked for me and I was able to publish to Azure :)
Hope this helps.

Comment: You got it, VS uses `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe` which apparently is an older version.

Answer (score 6):

Try deselecting `"Publish using PowerShell script"` checkbox in publish Settings

[image]

It worked for me