# Publish to Azure - 'Unrecognized link extension 'contentLibExtension'

Tags: asp.net, azure, webdeploy

When I go and right click my projects and hit publish and follow the steps I get the following error

Error: Unrecognized link extension 'contentLibExtension'.

I've tried everything mentioned here [Publish to Azure fails with " Unrecognized link extension 'contentLibExtension'" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056117/publish-to-azure-fails-with-unrecognized-link-extension-contentlibextension) and it still doesn't work.

Anyone run into this? I've been following this tutorial

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html#id4

I have ISS Express and SQL Server Express installed. Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: can you try to publish to local file system to see if it work?

Comment: Would you happen to know a guide that can do that? Or where I can find information on that. I'm literally following the tutorial and have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

publish method choose file system

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try!

Comment: @XiaominWu It says it sucessfully published when I do it locally

Comment: Also, not sure if this helps but when I hit "preview" it says failed and this is the message: "Web deployment task failed. (UnknowLinkExtension)"

Comment: not sure what it is. just try to publish to your file system. if it doesn`t work then it is your app`s issue.  if it is confirmed is your app`s issue. next step is to seperated one by one. e.g take out database dependency

Comment: I tried to publish to the file system already. And it succeeded.

Comment: i ran out of idea. but you can also a different way to deploy your app. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

Comment: No worries, thanks for helping.